# How to preview Dojo/Dijit themes?

Tags: themes, dojo

I bought the O'Reilly Dojo book by Matthew Russell.  It says "in your toolkit checkout, you can find a theme tester at dijit/themes/themeTester.html.

I downloaded 1.3.2 from here: http://dojotoolkit.com/downloads 
and cannot find such a file.  I would like to see each of the three themes in action. 
How can I do that?

Thanks,
Neal Walters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

themeTester isn't in the release (minified) version.  You need to download the *-src ones.  For example this one: http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.3.2/dojo-release-1.3.2-src.tar.gz.  These are available off of the 'More downloads' link on the downloads page.

Besides what [Wahnfireden said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341703/how-to-preview-dojo-dijit-themes/1341771#1341771), you can also check out [Dojocampus docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org).  It has examples embedded where you can dynamically change the theme applied to individual widgets (as well as change the version of dojo that is used).  For example, [dijit.form.Button](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/Button) has a bunch of examples to look at.

Answer (score 3):

[Dijit Theme Tester](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html)

Another great place to test out Dijit and DojoX widgets is to look at their tests. Dijit tests are [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/tests/), and DojoX tests are within each individual folder [here](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/).

Note that these links are to the nightly build, not 1.3.2, so there may be small differences. I'd suggest using the Dojo nightly though, personally.